# Wordpress show Today's posts organized by category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system

I need to create a "Today's Daily News" page for an internal company 'newspaper'. It is run on a wordpress, so the not-so-savvy can handle it. The page just needs to display a tree-ish view of the categories with ONLY TODAY's posts listed in them. If there are no news items in any of the categories for today, then they should not be displayed. I have found some useful bits of code which I can patch together to achieve this, but really I want to utilize as much of wordpress' built in functions as possible. This is the format I am looking for:

```
Today's Daily News

-Category 1

---News Item Title 1A

---News Item Title 1B

---News Item Title 1C

---News Item Title 1D


-Category 2

---News Item Title 2A

---News Item Title 2B
```

Comment: Which bit do you need help with - fetching today's posts, sorting them by category, emitting them back into the page, overall architecture, or something else? How far have you got?

Comment: fetching todays posts sorted by category. Then outputting one category at a time with the posts under it. Architecture/design I can handle that is not an issue. I almost figured it out using straight php/mysql, but I would like to use (and start learning) wordpress built in functions more. I have a feeling that what I looking for can be achieved by their framework and I would just be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I figured out how to get this to work. I create a page template called "Today's Post" and you can see the source below:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Today's Posts
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<ul>
<?php
$today = getdate();
$categories = get_categories("orderby=name&parent=0");
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    query_posts('year='.$today["year"].'&monthnum='.$today["mon"].'&day='.$today["mday"].'&post_type=post&post_status=publish&cat='.$category->term_id);
    echo "  <li>\n"
        ."    <a href=\"".get_category_link($category->term_id)."\">".$category->name."</a>\n"
        ."    <ul>\n";
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
    endwhile;
    echo "    </ul>\n"
        ."  </li>\n";
}
?>
</ul>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

To show child categories, remove "&parent=0" and likewise change it to a category ID if you just want to display that categories children.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your custom post query and ordering using either one of the following functions/techniques:

1. The [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function
2. [Custom queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) using filter methods to sort/order posts